# Heroku is not displaying all my data: the posts are missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Though the tables are present in PG database on Heroku, the the post page returns a blank page with this message:

"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Heroku logs returns this: (relevant part)

```
 Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Your database configuration is probably wrong?

Comment: Please add whole log, please add output of heroku rake db:migrate

Comment: Here is the output from both commands:                            'code' heroku run rake db:migrate and 'code' heroku logs:                                                                     [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KaYxUxN7QDdWrT64UWrEFzlzS9oPL0641lTREjfpSG0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, Sunspot was causing the error:

On Heroku, sunspot gems are not supported. So, you have 2 choices:

1. You either buy Heroku Websolr add-on, if you're willing to shell off $20  a month.
2. Or, you can get rid off sunspot gems. This is exactly what we did and all the missing tables displayed beautifully.

   As to the full text search, and to replace sunspot, we're thinking of using PG because it has this feature built in in combination with gems like 'texticle and 'texticle/rails.'
   I will post the update once the solution has been implemented.